# c# automapper always convert null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, automapper, blazor-server-side

automapper always convert null objects and it not throwing any exception here is my models and the methos i used...what i want when i initialize ProductDetailsModel inside ProductModel model i want to be initialized also inside Product model... both objects ProductDetailsModel and CategoryModel inside ProductModel they not initialized in Product

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? IDCategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IDCategory")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; } 

}


 public class ProductModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="حقل الزامي")]
    public int? IDCategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل الزامي")]
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "يجب ادخال ارقام فقط")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "حقل الزامي")]
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "يجب ادخال ارقام فقط")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<ImageModel> Images { get; set; } = new List<ImageModel>();
    public CategoryModel CategoryModel { get; set; } = new CategoryModel();
    public ProductDetailsModel ProductModelDetails { get; set; } = new ProductDetailsModel();
}


 public class ProfileMapper : Profile
{
    public ProfileMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<ProductModel, Product>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ImageModel, Image>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<CategoryModel, Category>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ProductDetailsModel, ProductDetails>().ReverseMap();

        

    }
}


public async Task Add(ProductModel entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var theObject = mapper.Map<ProductModel, Product>(entity);
            await Db.Product.AddAsync(theObject);
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await jSRuntime.ToastrError(e.Message);

        }

    }

private async Task AddProductsForm()
{

    await UnitOfWork.ProductRepository.Add(new ProductModel {ProductModelDetails = new ProductDetailsModel { Details="gg"},Images = new List<ImageModel> { new ImageModel { ImageUrl = defaultImage } } });
    await UnitOfWork.Complete();
    ProductModels = (ICollection<ProductModel>)await UnitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetALL();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping does not include the name changes.
For example from Category => CategoryModel

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Category))
    .ReverseMap();
```